# I found instructions on how to make nerve gas. Is it possible to be real?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, synthesis, chemical-weapons

I just happened to find instructions how to make nerve gas. I found it on the Deep web. And since I know next to nothing about chemistry, I'm gonna ask here:

**Is it possible to make nerve gas according to the instructions below? And if it is, how hard is it and how hard it is to acquire ingredients?**

It just boggles me that something like this would be available, even on the Deep web. It's like complete instructions to make nuclear bomb, except plutonium is harder to come by, right?

Thanks for answering and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBJgV.png)'s the link to the image, because it's pretty big and comprehensive.

Comment: Well, if presence of such receipts disturbs you, than why are you asking if they are ok, using a link? Many explosives, drugs or gases aren't difficult to make. On the other hand access to firearms is so easy in many places that, in comparison, it can be considered minor problem.

Comment: Well, you certainly can produce lots of stuff that kills. But, can you do them on an industrial scale that would actually pose a threat? Hmm, not if you have better things to do with your money.

Comment: Once you have mastered all skills needed to follow that recipe, you are probably old and wise enough not to do that. Just by guessing it is at the edge of what a PhD in synthetic organic chemistry can survive, literally.

Comment: *Mithoron*: It does not disturbs me, it boggles me. I always thought that knowledge like this is kept in secrecy in some highly guarded labs. I am full aware that full country armed with guns is much more horrible. But this is somehow offtopic. *inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M*: I asked if that recipe is real, not "create nerve gas in industrial quantities". It is somehow apparent even to me that this thing is out of reach for normal criminals/humans. *ssavec*: So it's real, no buzzwords put together to be intimidating - "hey guise i creatud nerve gus"...

Comment: I don't think many would confirm or deny if it's real, for lots of obvious reasons. Like the problem you have with the release of such a receipt in the first place...

Comment: I am genuinely scared.That SUCH RECIPES are available on net is INERADICABLE.If you are BOGGLED by this WHY SHARE AND SPREAD? why?

Answer (score 6):

Some nerve gases are very simple chemicals so it is likely that the instructions are real.

This, however, isn't the point. They are very hard to make without killing yourself in the process and acquiring the ingredients is often very hard as governments restrict the supply and monitor uses very carefully. Even research scientists in approved facilities may not be allowed access to the key ingredients (I've had this for legitimate uses while doing real research).

Even if they ingredients are obtainable, the expertise to handle the products safely are not and almost nobody is likely to be able to apply the recipes safely. A similar situation exists for conventional and nuclear explosives. The recipes are available (e.g. for nitroglycerine or a simple uranium nuclear bomb). Both require both large, expensive facilities to avoid self-destruction or death by radiation. So the apparently simple recipes are useless unless you are major industrial enterprise or a government.

We're safe, despite the recipes.

Comment: Chlorine gas was used in WWI. Just mix bleach and ammonia which are both common household chemicals. Read about someone getting killed doing this every so often. http://articles.philly.com/1995-01-09/news/25712055_1_household-chemicals-bleach-ammonia